# Unable to remove winehq from repositories used by apt-get

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, wine, repository

How can I remove a repository from apt-get? I know this is a duplicate, but the existing answers didn't work for me.

When I run `apt-get update` I'm getting the following error:

```
Err:13 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                            
The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 76F1A20FF987672F
```

I don't need wine anymore so I've been trying to remove it.

When I run `sudo apt-cache policy`, I can see Wine's repository listed as follows:

```
500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
 release v=16.04,o=dl.winehq.org,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=winehq,c=main,b=i386
 origin dl.winehq.org
500 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
 release v=16.04,o=dl.winehq.org,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=winehq,c=main,b=amd64
 origin dl.winehq.org
```

I've tried various different syntaxes to remove the repository but nothing works. Here are some of the things I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial inRelease'
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'deb https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu ./'
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu ./'
sudo apt-add-repository --remove 'https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the file containing a link to that repo from `/etc/apt/sources.list.d` or from `/etc/apt.sources.list` file.

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me

```
sudo add-apt-repository --remove wine-builds
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. There you'll see some files. You'll understand what those files are just by looking at them. Then open a terminal there by right-clicking. Then type `sudo rm <filename>`. Replace  with the file you want to remove.